# The result of query is different between the client side and the domain service class in a Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, eager-loading, domainservices

I have a query that brings the whole graph of an object:

```
IQueryable<Rapport> rap = this.ObjectContext.Rapport.Include("Filtre")
                                  .Include("Filtre.FiltreValeur")
                                  .Include("Tri")
                                  .Include("Section")
                                  .Include("Section.ChampTexte")
                                  .Include("Section.ChampTexte.MiseEnForme")
                                  .Include("Section.Attribut")
                                  .Include("Section.Attribut.MiseEnForme")
                                  .Where(r => r.PK_Rapport == PK_Rapport);
```

The content of the variable rap is loaded as requested. My problem is that when loading the query, the node "Section" is empty, knowing that it's full at the domain service level.
I load the query as following:

```
EntityQuery<Rapport> query = _context.GetRapportCompletByIDQuery(_rapport.PK_Rapport);
            _context.Load(query).Completed += (sender1, args1) =>
            {
                this._RapportComplet = ((LoadOperation<Rapport>)sender1).Entities.AsQueryable<Rapport>().First();};
```

I have no clew how to resolve this. :( HELP!

Comment: How do you communicate between the client and the service? WCF?

Comment: I'm using the WCF RIA Services, i have a domain service class

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure Section has the [Include] directive in your DomainService.Metadata File.

Comment: The node "Filtre" doesn't have this flag and it's full. I don't think it's a metadata related problem.